# Checking how many rows there are in a .csv file in terminal

Tags: python, pandas, looker-studio

am creating a dataframe and writing it to .csv file. I know that it has more than 1m rows, because once I open it in excel it reaches the limit of 1,048,576 rows.

If I use `wc -l seconddataset.csv` terminal prints out `100001`, why is that? When I print out pandas `df` in terminal it only shows `100000` rows. Whereas it actually has more.

Also, I am importing `seconddataset.csv` to google's data studio and I see that not all rows are imported. I feel like some of my rows are being dropped before being imported.

Are there any funky stuff happening with `DataFrame` or `df.to_csv()`?

Parts of my code:

```
def initialize_analyticsreporting():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

    # Build the service object.
    analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

    return analytics


def get_report(analytics):
    '''Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

    Args:
      analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
    Returns:
      The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
    '''

    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                    'pageSize': 100000000,
                    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '90daysAgo', 'endDate': 'yesterday'}],
                    'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:adClicks'}, {'expression': 'ga:impressions'}, {'expression': 'ga:adCost'}, {'expression': 'ga:CTR'}, {'expression': 'ga:CPC'}, {'expression': 'ga:costPerTransaction'}, {'expression': 'ga:transactions'}, {'expression': 'ga:transactionsPerSession'}, {'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}, {'expression': 'ga:timeOnPage'}],
                    'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:adMatchedQuery'}, {'name': 'ga:campaign'}, {'name': 'ga:adGroup'}, {'name': 'ga:adwordsCustomerID'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}],
                    'orderBys': [{'fieldName': 'ga:impressions', 'sortOrder': 'DESCENDING'}]
                }]
        }
    ).execute()


def print_response(response):
    global df
    list = []
    # get report data
    for report in response.get('reports', []):
        # set column headers
        columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
        dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
        metricHeaders = columnHeader.get(
            'metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
        rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
        # create dict for each row
        dict = {}
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

        # fill dict with dimension header (key) and dimension value (value)
        for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
            dict[header] = dimension

        # fill dict with metric header (key) and metric value (value)
        for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
            for metric, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                # set int as int, float a float
                if ',' in value or '.' in value:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                else:
                    dict[metric.get('name')] = int(value)

        list.append(dict)

    df = pd.DataFrame(list)
    return df


analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
response = get_report(analytics)
print_response(response)
```

```
0
1
2
...
99997
99998
99999
[100000 rows x 36 columns]
```

The df is not empty, I just didn't bother to include the data.

Then I rename columns and add new ones, then I export the file:

```
df.to_csv('SecondDataset.csv', encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I would be hard to know without seeing your python code.

Comment: There are 500 lines of code, I'll edit the answer to include the parts of it.

Comment: As for the `wc -l` telling you there is one more line that you expect, it's because of the header line with the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

Pandas creates range based column names. You could see them using `df.columns`.

The one extra row is the column names created by pandas.

If you don't want the extra row, save using,

```
df.to_csv('SecondDataset.csv', header=False)
```